# Is there a linear commit history for any branch in git repository? And how do you specify it to git format-patch?

Tags: git

1. Does a linear commit history exist for any branch head in a git repository, all the way back to an empty git repo? Essentially a list of commits in its history, whose diffs when applied in order can get the empty repo to current state of the branch?
2. Is there "git format-patch" command that can extract that linear commit history
3. Specifically, that extracted series of patches should should be usable in with a "git init ; git am patches.txt" to reconstruct the latest branch head state, without running into patch conflicts

Even if it means a bit of scripting to achieve what I want above.

----- Question as asked initially --------

I have a git repoA and checked out say branch branchX

I want to generate a sequence of patches with "git format-patch" that i can use to rebuild a brand new git repo using "git am/apply" from scratch(git init) with just that one branchX and its complete history going back to commit zero.

Currently I tried getting the patch as follows from repoA

```
git --no-pager format-patch --binary --stdout --root branchX > patch.list
OR
# f7ef86f26066fb428305f3809309ba33d70a9feb is considered the zero/empty state/commit of any git repo
git --no-pager format-patch --binary --stdout --root f7ef86f26066fb428305f3809309ba33d70a9feb branchX > patch.list
cd /path/to/repoNew
git init
git am --3way patch.list
OR
git am patch.list
```

But some how the patch.list generated by above format-patch command

```
bash-4.2$ git am --3way /witspace/sarvi/space_sarvi_mynxos/kwaiclean/boot/t
Applying: Initial branch reference point created
applying to an empty history
Applying: Admin created refpoint (likely to handle manual repository mucking)
Applying: new-module-makes
Applying: new-module-makes
Applying: new file for sienna target
Applying: change the rule for specifying EXTRA_*
Applying: Removing Makefile.am files and modifying copyright entry
Applying: changes for bringing up isan-image on maui
Applying: Adding group 'routing-sw' to /etc/group. The routing-sw components will be             
started by sysmgr in process group 'routing-sw'. This will allow us to kill/ restart 
all routing-sw components without rebooting Linux/SANOS.
Applying: added a new dhcpd.conf file that is specific to 13-slot
Applying: modify the /etc/dhcpd.conf in each lc-line entry to specifiy the slot 
number as     part of creating DHCP links to correct LCImage
Applying: Update build infrastructure for DC3 builds
Applying: Use our own passwd/group files instead of using the one in basefs
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       aci/bootglobalpkg/group
.git/rebase-apply/patch:34: new blank line at EOF.
+
warning: 1 line adds whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging aci/bootglobalpkg/group
Applying: Changes for preparation of new restructure of workspace
Applying: DC-OS Codebase Restructure: Stage1 + Stage2 for branch sf
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       aci/bootbios_program/module.mk
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging aci/bootbios_program/module.mk
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in aci/bootbios_program/module.mk
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0015 DC-OS Codebase Restructure: Stage1 + Stage2 for branch sf
hint: Use 'git am --show-current-patch=diff' to see the failed patch
When you have resolved this problem, run "git am --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git am --skip" instead.
To restore the original branch and stop patching, run "git am --abort".
bash-4.2$
```

What I am not getting is if "git format-patch" command, above does get/generates all the commits/patches from initialization of the source/original git repo, in the right order,
and the "git am" command only applies them in that same sequence, why would there be conflicts?

How do do this right ?

Why is it not possible to start with a branch head, walk linearly to the first commit and get the sequence of patches in order and apply them in a branch new git repo to reproduce that linear history through patches.

Comment: Just a wild guess: Do you have files with CRLF line endings instead of LF? Then you should add `--keep-cr` to the `git am` command.

Comment: tried that. doest seem to be helping

Comment: Commits, in a Git repository, form a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG). The format-patch walks part of the DAG, producing a linear representation in which merge commits are discarded; non-empty non-merge commits are converted from snapshot-and-metadata to text-and-diff. The resulting diffs form purely linear chains, from which the original DAG *cannot be recovered* as the merges have been discarded.

Comment: In short, you're trying to do something that cannot and should not be tried.

Comment: If git is a DAG, then it should be possible to walked from a branch head to the original empty git repo state aka first commit, then why is it not possible as a sequence of incremental commits/changes,  to get a sequence of diffs or patches that can be used to rebuild just that linear history without any conflicts ?
That doest seem to make sense to me

Comment: As  understood the documentation, the --root option and fact that I provided  "4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904" which is alays the first empty commit of any git repo, I provided the first and the last commits to walk a linear history

Comment: Draw a DAG with several branch points followed by merge nodes. Then, walk the graph from start to end, visiting both branches, but omitting the merge nodes. Now imagine applying each diff produced by this walk, one element at a time. What happens?

Comment: It seems you are copying a branch from one repository to another?

Comment: @SarviShanmugham A DAG can have multiple nodes with no incoming edges. If your DAG has just one such edge, it's called a tree.

Comment: As jthill noted, fast-export and fast-import and/or filter-branch are probably closer to the right tools for the job here. It's not completely clear, from what you've posted so far, exactly what the job *is* (interweave commits in different repos? combine them somehow?) but whatever it is, format-patch + am are the wrong tools.

Comment: I think any branch head state of the tree can be built with a sequences of commits/patches that go back to the empty state of the repo. The question is if I can identifiy the "right" list of commits/patches that walk back to empty repo that will "git am" without conflicts to produce branchX head again

Comment: I haven't seen it said clearly yet, so here it is: **A linear commit history back to the first commit in the repository exists for *every* branch, and you can see that history with `git log`.**

Comment: If that is the case, if I had a script, that walked the list of commits from the very first commit, and did "git format-patch" for each one of them, then they should apply without conflicts? Are there any recommended git format-patch options I should be using? And should I be be using "git am" or "git am --3way" to patch with out conflicts when I get the patches for each commit it "git log"

Answer (score 1):

```
git push path/to/new/repo branchX
```

will do it if you have a path to the new repo from the old, or sub in a url for the path if it's hosted somewhere reachable. Otherwise

```
git bundle create my.bundle branchX
# get my.bundle to the destination system somehow, then in your new repo
git fetch my.bundle branchX
```

> I want to generate a sequence of patches with "git format-patch" that i can use to rebuild a brand new git repo using "git am/apply" from scratch(git init) with just that one branchX and its complete history going back to commit zero.

That's the wrong tool for this job.  As @torek points out, format-patch is built for patch-series work, communicating linear history.

Comment: we are trying to combine 2 different component repo trees into one tree with 2 subdirectory compA and compB at its root.
Towards this we are using got format-patch --src-prefix=a/compA --prefix=a/compB to generate the line series of patch from the compA/ and compA/ git repositories with the above prefix options 

I am reallly looking for a way to translate branchX into a series of patches that can result in the current state of branchX.

Comment: filter-branch and read-tree were built for that. format-patch was really not.  How were you planning to match up commit ancestries when you have two different non-linear histories?

Comment: to be very clear: you can do what you're trying to do with Git, just not the way you're trying to do it. Sure, if Git didn't already have vastly better tools for doing what you want, the one you're trying to use might have been goosed until it could be bludgeoned into service, but when you've got a screwdriver on the wall, insistently trying to make your awl drive screws is just senseless.

Comment: What tools would be the right ones to use if I wanted to do the following
1. take 2 git repos compA and compB, that have commits in them were made together in a co-ordinated fashion
2. turn it into 1 git repo with subdirectories compA/ and compB/ init
3. During the process, I want to take those co-ordinated commits  from compA and compB,  that happenned and combine them into a single commit acrosa compA and compB in the new repo>

What i was trying to generate a sequence patches with format-patch and  "prefix" and apply them from compA and. compB

Comment: Isnt the key question here 
1. Is there a linear history from the head of branchX back to an empty repositories
2. How do we choose to generate format-patch for that linear history

Comment: I'd do this with filter-branch's index filter and read-tree. If your project is private, you can use `git fast-export --anonymize` to publish just the structure for discussion, fast-import those into new repos, put those up on say github, edit this question to explain what you're trying to achieve and linking to the anonymized repos so there's something concrete to talk about. How exactly you identify which commits go together is the big question here, and what I'm proposing looks to me like the quickest way to find common ground rather than discovering questions iteratively.

Comment: No, those are questions based on pre-conceived notions that would be very easy to correct if you'd do as I suggest and put anonymized versions if your history up so there's something concrete to talk about.

Comment: for starters, lets ignore the problem of combining commits, and address one fundamental question, how do you get a list of diffs/patches that covers "a" linear list of commits from branchX that, that when applied(git am possibly) to an empty git repository can take take it to the state of branchX.  This to me sounds like a fundamental building block that I can build on. I dont need to push a repository for it. It could any repository with multiple branches and syncs/merges between them. I just want to get a list of commits/diffs from zero to head of branch that will apply without conflicts